# Sleep inside of setInterval without freezing the browser

Tags: javascript, setinterval, sleep

I have a function called "loop" which is being called repetitively using setInterval(). Inside of that function I need another function which has to be called "delay()" (it has to be the exact syntax).

So I ended up with this:

```
function loop() {
    console.log("some code")
    delay(100)
    console.log("some more code")
    delay(100)
}



if (typeof loop != "undefined")
    window.loopInterval = setInterval(loop, 1)

function delay(millis) {
    var now = Date.now();
    while(Date.now() < now + millis){} 
}
```

This works just fine, but it freezes the browser making it unable to render certain changes properly.
Now is there any way I could change the delay function so that it simply temporarely pauses the setInterval?

As I said the syntax with the loop and delay function has to remain intact. And yes I have good reasons for that.

**For all those who didn't believe me that I do in fact have a very good reason, here you go: https://github.com/T-vK/LedStripSimulator

Code written for Arduinos almost always uses the loop() function and delay() is also a very common thing on Arduinos as they often only do one thing at a time anyways. And a JS simulator whose purpose it is to replicate the Arduino syntax as accurately as possible certainly needs a synchronous delay function.**

Comment: Simple answer: No. Don't tell us how you plan to accomplish something, tell us the problem you're trying to solve. (And the problem you're trying to solve is not "How can I make this work" when it simply cannot by nature of how browsers are designed)

Comment: Nope. Can't do it with your "exact syntax"

Comment: That's not the correct way to cause delay. That will obviously halt the script execution until the while loop exits. You can use `setTimeout` which should solve the problem in much elegant way.

Comment: @DarkFalcon I never told you how I would want to accomplish this! My problem simply is that I need a delay function to work similar to a sleep function, but without freezing the thread. And only because you don't know a solution doesn't mean that there is none.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question cannot be answered because it violates the architectural design of the technology in question.

Comment: @DarkFalcon This is pathetic...

Comment: Close-vote and down-vote all day long. I don't care. It is possible. Deal with it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Edit: [Here is a complete project I've been working on that easily demonstrates that it works.](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/T-vK/LedStripSimulator/blob/master/index.html)

I figured it out... I just had to run my code in a separate thread. In that thread I can sleep all day long and the DOM rendering won't be affected.

(Browser has to support webworkers)

```js
//Code that runs in a separate thread:
var blob = new Blob([`
    function loop() {
        console.log("some code");
        delay(1000);
        console.log("some more code");
        delay(1000);
    }
    function delay(millis) {
        var now = Date.now();
        while(Date.now() < now + millis){} ;
    }
    if (typeof loop != "undefined")
        setInterval(loop, 1);
`], { type: "text/javascript" });

var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

//Code that runs in the UI thread:
var text = 'This text will be added to this div letter by letter without any freezing from the delay() function.';
var currentLetter = 0;
var maxLetter = text.length-1;
var div = document.getElementById('lagFree');

setInterval(function() {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + text[currentLetter];
    if (currentLetter >= maxLetter) {
        div.innerHTML = '';
        currentLetter = 0;
    } else
        currentLetter++;
},10);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="lagFree"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in your console, it prints "some code" and "some more code" again and again with a 1000ms synchronous delay in between. And even though we do that, the UI doesn't freeze and the text animation runs smoothly.